# Subbing Variable into a ML model

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I want a function to take in a model parameter as a variable and sub that parameter into the ML model.

Example is:

```
def create_model(model_class):
    return sk.linear_model.{model_class}
```

I think it should be done using classes but i'm pretty lost.

I've tried creating a class but cannot get the output to be the ML model object.

Comment: Do you mean that based on the user input you return different classes, like a factory function of some kind? Or do you mean that a model has an attribute model.attribute and you want to change the attribute through a function? You'll have to elaborate a little.

Comment: Yes the model has a model attribute and I want to change the attribute through the function input. The specific model is a sk.linear_model, and the input is the attribute Ridge. So the final model would be sk.linear_model.Ridge.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why, but I think you're looking for something like this?

```
from sklearn import linear_model

def create_model(model_style: str, **kwargs):
    """Model builder

    Args:
        model_style: which type of linear model you want to use
        kwargs: kwargs for initializing the model_style

    Returns:
        sklearn linear model class
    """
    valid_models = vars(linear_model)['__all__']
    if model_style not in valid_models:
        raise ValueError("model_style is not valid")
    else:
        return getattr(linear_model, model_style)(**kwargs)

ridge = create_model('Ridge')
foo = create_model('foo')  # error
```